# text-align: center; doesnt align correctly

Tags: html, css

I have a piece of text which i need to align in the middle of the page, but it doesnt work

```
<div style="width:100%; border: 0px black solid;text-align:center; height:25px;">
        <font size="4">
        <div id="kategorioverskrift">
        <strong>1 Generelt</strong>
        </div>
        </font>
    </div>
```

I have made a jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/2gN4a/

It is the divs above "kategorioverskrift" that are the issue.

Does anyone know how to fix this?
Thx

Comment: [validate, validate, validate](http://validator.w3.org/)

Comment: The real website requires login

Comment: — That does not stop you validating the markup.

Comment: There are so many problems I am not sure where to begin, I would recommend running the page through W3C Validator fix all issues they report and see if the problem persists. Quentin I did not see your comment could not agree more!!!

Comment: WOAH!!! 135 errors and 10 warnings! I just had to validate when I saw `link` tags in the body and that you were using the font tag (above) with HTML 5.

Comment: Quite frankly, this page is beyond salvageability. I'm not trying to be rude but before you do anything else, you need to visit http://validator.w3.org/ and validate your page. Then, read up on HTML at http://w3schools.com/html/default.asp.

Comment: Will do :) There are some errors, true. But the site works fine. Also, i think the validator gives errors at some unnecessary points, like providing alt attributes to img tags. But thats just me.

Comment: Also, it gives a lot of errors for custom attributes on input tags. WHY? You should not validate it against HTML5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the above `div` outside it's current parent `div` http://jsfiddle.net/2gN4a/3/